# How to use multiple belongsTo in bookshelfjs?

Tags: node.js, angular, foreign-keys, angular2-forms, bookshelf.js

i have one Table with name "**class**" and it has two foreign key **attendance_id** and **syllabus_id**, but using JOIN i can get only one foreign key value, here is my Model,

```
var AttendanceType = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'attendance_type',
});
var SyllabusName = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'syllabus_name',});
var Class = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'class',
AttendanceRef: function() {
   return this.belongsTo(AttendanceType);
},
SyllabusRef: function() {
   return this.belongsTo(SyllabusName);
}
});
module.exports = Class;
```

HERE is my controller,

```
.fetchAll({ withRelated: ['AttendanceRef','SyllabusRef']})
```

but i get only data from "**attendance_type**" Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var AttendanceType = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'attendance_type',
});

var syllabusName = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'syllabus_name',
});

var Class = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'class',
   AttendanceRef: function() {
      return this.belongsTo(AttendanceType,'attendance_type_id');
   },
   SyllabusNameRef: function() {
      return this.belongsTo(syllabusName,'syllabus_id');
   }
});
module.exports = Class;
```

here is my Controller.

```
.fetchAll({ withRelated: ['AttendanceRef','SyllabusNameRef']})
```

Comment: So, the real problem was that the foreign key for the `syllabus_name` table wasn't using the convention that Bookshelf was expecting, which is the singular form of the table name with `_id` appended to the end: `syllabus_name_id`. Since you're using a different foreign key you have to specify it as the second argument to `.belongsTo()`.